# Can I access my files from a command line of root@nameEm250: ?

Tags: 11.10

My upgrade to 11.10 failed some how. Now I can't get Ubuntu to reboot. I get a command line and now I just want to go and save my documents, pictures, ect. and just do a clean install. How do I access my files to back them up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use live cd and backup your data and then do fresh install. Choose `Try Ubuntu` in ubuntu installation process.

If you have a separate home partition you can recover your data if you donot format it during installation.[Although you can use the same mount point]

From command line you could recover your data if you know basic shell commands:

`cd /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/` is the path where documents and pictures are located.
 Just do `cp` to copy your data. I think you will need `mount` as well to use your external drive if you have one.

So basically

`sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sd[abc][123] SOME_PATH`[Given You have a FAT pen drive]

`cp -r /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/* SOME_PATH/FOLDER`